# Parallelize function on dictionary in IPython

Tags: dictionary, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-parallel

Up till now, I have parallelized functions by mapping them on to lists that are distributed out to the various clusters using the function `map_sync(function, list)` .

Now, I need to run a function on each entry of a dictionary.

map_sync does not seem work on dictionaries. I have also tried to scatter the dictionary and use decorators to run the function in parallel. However, dictionaries dont seem to lend themselves to scattering either. **Is there some other way to parallelize functions on dictionaries without having to convert to lists?**

These are my attempts thus far:

```
from IPython.parallel import Client
rc = Client()
dview = rc[:]

test_dict = {'43':"lion", '34':"tiger", '343':"duck"}
dview.scatter("test",test)

dview["test"]
# this yields [['343'], ['43'], ['34'], []] on 4 clusters
# which suggests that a dictionary can't be scattered?
```

Needless to say, when I run the function itself, I get an error:

```
@dview.parallel(block=True)
def run():
    for d,v in test.iteritems():
        print d,v

run()
```

AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last) in ()
 in run(dict)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

I don't know if it's relevant, but I'm using an IPython Notebook connected to Amazon AWS clusters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scatter a dict with:

```
def scatter_dict(view, name, d):
    """partition a dictionary across the engines of a view"""
    ntargets = len(view)
    keys = d.keys() # list(d.keys()) in Python 3
    for i, target in enumerate(view.targets):
        subd = {}
        for key in keys[i::ntargets]:
            subd[key] = d[key]
        view.client[target][name] = subd

scatter_dict(dview, 'test', test_dict)
```

and then operate on it remotely, as you normally would.

You can also gather the remote dicts into one local one again with:

```
def gather_dict(view, name):
    """gather dictionaries from a DirectView"""
    merged = {}
    for d in view.pull(name):
        merged.update(d)
    return merged

gather_dict(dv, 'test')
```

[An example notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5606534)